# Statements True or False? Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, limsup-and-liminf

(a) If the set $S$ of subsequential limits of $(x_n)$ is empty, then $(x_n)$ is unbounded.

(b) If $a$ is an eventual upper bound for $(x_n)$ and $b$ is an eventual upper
bound for $(b_n)$, then $a-b$ is an eventual upper bound for $(a_n − b_n)$.

Using definitions of subsequential limits and eventual upper bounds, I need to show if these statements are true. Otherwise, I need to give a counterexample to disprove them.

I'm having a hard time with these. Here's what I'm thinking so far:

eventual upper bound is $limsup$ of $x_n$.
By definition: $lim sup_{n→∞} x_n$ = inf{$β : ∃ N$ such that $x_n < β, ∀ n ≥ N$}.

a) If set $S$ of subsequential limits is empty, then the subsequences do not converge. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence. By contrapositive, no convergent subsequences are contained in an unbounded sequence. So, $x_n$ unbounded. I can't come up with a counterexample for this, but I wasn't really sure.

b) $lim sup_{n→∞} a_n=a$ and $lim sup_{n→∞} b_n = b$. But does this always imply $lim sup_{n→∞} (a_n-b_n) = a-b$. I can't really come up with a counterexample for this, but I think it's true.

$lim sup_{n→∞} (a_n-b_n) = lim sup_{n→∞} a_n - lim sup_{n→∞} b_n = a-b$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Your sequence is unbounded. How is it a counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already answered first part. $(x_n)$ is necessarily unbounded, by Bolzano -Weierstrass Theorem.

Take $a_n=1$ and $b_n=-n$. Then $1$ is an essential upper bound for $(a_n)$ and  $0$ is an essential uper bound for $(b_n)$ but $a_n-b_n$ is not bounded.

Comment: so $a_n =1$ is constant sequence $1,1,1,....$? So the $limsup$ for it just be $1$, and $limsup$ for $-n = 0$. But, $limsup(a_n-b_n) = limsup(1-(-n)) = limsup(1+n) = $\infty$$ So, it diverges, and is not equal to $1$. Thank you for the help, I just want to make sure my logic is following properly. For part a), was everything about my answer correct

Comment: @eddie Yes, your answer for part a) is correct.